# Особенность работы lambda с сигналами/слотами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, lambda

Есть большая программа с двумя окнами и большим количеством сигналов\слотов. Заметил, что при комментировании части кода с сигналам перестаёт запускаться второе окно. В итоге программа сократилась до:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Win1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win1, self).__init__()
        self.enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.enter.setText('Enter')
        self.enter.setDefault(True)
        self.enter.clicked.connect(self.go_ahead)

    def go_ahead(self):
        self.hide()
        app2 = Win2()
        app2.show()


class Win2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win2, self).__init__()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText('second')
        self.pushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.send())

    def send(self):
        print('ff')


app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
start_win = Win1()
start_win.show()
sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

В таком виде программа нормально запускается. При комментировании `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.send())` перестаёт открываться `Win2`. Оказалось, что надо писать `self.app2 = Win2()`, а не `app2 = Win2()`(что тоже не совсем понятно).

Дальнейший анализ показал, что использование `lambda` в сигнале\слоте позволяет использовать запись `app2 = Win2()`, т.е. с `.connect(lambda: self.send())` всё работает, а с `.connect(self.send)` второе окно не запускается. Подобное поведение не только с сигналом `clicked`, но и с `textChanged`, `timeout`, `cursorPositionChanged` да и скорее всего со всеми.

Означает ли подобное поведение, что `lambda` делает `app2` атрибутом `Win1`? Если нет, то что всё таки происходит?

Comment: Не, `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close)` а `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())`, т.к. `close` нужно вызывать, это же функция. А лучше без лямбд: `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)`

Comment: @gil9red, функция под `connect` - для примера. В реальном случае у меня другие

Comment: Понял... думаю при `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())` происходит замыкание и ссылка на текущий объект сохраняется в функции (лямбде) из-за чего и не происходит удаление объекта :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Оказалось, что надо писать self.app2 = Win2(), а не app2 = Win2()(что
> тоже не совсем понятно).

Это логично, т.к. если объект не имеет ссылок, то он уничтожается, а при `app2 = Win2()` объект `Win2` имеет ссылку только в переменной `app2`, а после выхода функции эта переменная выходит из своей области действия и уничтожается, а на `Win2` уменьшает количество ссылок и оно становится 0, поэтому он уничтожается.

Поэтому, когда вы написали `self.app2`, вы в текущем объекте создали атрибут `app2` и теперь он ссылается на `Win2` и теперь пока существует текущий объект `Win2` тоже будет существовать.

**НО**, можно обойтись только `app2`, если указывать родителя у виджета, тогда объект будет иметь ссылку на другой объект и останется в памяти

---

> Дальнейший анализ показал, что использование lambda в сигнале\слоте
> позволяет использовать запись app2 = Win2(), т.е. с .connect(lambda:
> self.close) всё работает, с .connect(self.close) второе окно не
> запускается.

Вообще, разница `.connect(lambda:self.close)` и `.connect(self.close)` проявится только при выполнении клика. В первом случае `self.close` не будет вызван, а во-втором будет (попробуйте в коде вызвать `self.close` и `self.close()`, и увидите, что метод в первом случае не был вызван).

---

> Означает ли подобное поведение, что lambda делает app2 атрибутом Win1?
> Если нет, то что всё таки происходит?

Думаю при `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())` **происходит замыкание** и ссылка на текущий объект сохраняется в функции (лямбде) из-за чего и не происходит удаление объекта

---

Вы ведь прячете первое окно, а второе окно не имеет ссылок на первое, поэтому не сможет на него воздействовать.

**Мне кажется, в вашем случае, самое то будет работать с `QStackedWidget`**. Сделаете главное окно, добавите на него те два виджета и у `QStackedWidget` через методы `setCurrentIndex` и/или `setCurrentWidget` переключайтесь между окнами.

Немного доработал ваш код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Win1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.enter.setText('Enter')
        self.enter.setDefault(True)
        self.enter.clicked.connect(self.go_ahead)

    def go_ahead(self):
        self.hide()

        self.app2 = Win2(self)
        self.app2.show()


class Win2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app1):
        super().__init__()

        self.app1 = app1

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText('second')
        self.pushButton.setDefault(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    def on_click(self):
        self.hide()
        self.app1.show()
        self.close()


app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
start_win = Win1()
start_win.show()
sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

Comment: "Вообще, разница .connect(lambda:self.close) и .connect(self.close) проявится только при выполнении клика." - понял о чём вы говорите, но я немного о другом. Немного поправил код. Разница проявляется в том, что с lambda  ссылка на Win2 не удаляется и дело не в том, будет ли вызван метод под функцией или нет.

Comment: По поводу `QStackedWidget` - спасибо за подсказку, но, наверное, в моём случае он не поможет. `QStackedWidget` же не может быть разных размеров для разных окон?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, текущую задачу с переключением окон лучше решать через виджет, специально для этого созданного – [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Win1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.enter.setText('Enter')
        self.enter.setDefault(True)


class Win2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText('second')
        self.pushButton.setDefault(True)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.win1 = Win1()
        self.win2 = Win2()

        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.win1)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.win2)

        # Настройка переключения между окнами
        self.win1.enter.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.win2.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    start_win = MainWindow()
    start_win.show()

    sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```